# How to detected the outliers?

Tags: python, outliers

I have a plot of value river kilometers and this value should be smooth on the graph, because it represents the track of the vichle, and the kilometers can not jump.
I found a scipy.signal library and the `find_peaks function`
But i could not find the appropriate parameters.
I read that the best is `prominence`, but it couldnt find the peaks that i need.
I also tried to use distance, but the results also don't satisfy me

```
x = df.river_km

# find peaks
#peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, distance = 150)
peaks, properties = find_peaks(x, prominence=1)
```

My result:[image]
What i expected:[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can simply iterate over the data and check whether the difference between two consecutive values exceeds a certain threshold. If so, remove the second. This would of course only work if the peaks are one point wide. Is this the case?

Comment: You can try this `peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=0)` followed by `plt.plot(x)` and then `plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")`

Comment: Yes, the first i try to do this, but then i saw that there are picks that comes on e after other.. and it didnt work

Comment: I'm not sure who you are responding to, but if there aren't *many* peaks in a row, a simple approach like that might just work. `peaks = []` `current_value =0` `for i in range(1,len(data)): if (data[i] - data[current_value]) > threshold: peaks.append(i) continue else: current_value = i`

Comment: Try setting the prominence to a higher value. From your graph all your `y-axis` are in values up till a thousand. Hence setting a prominence value of 1 means those peaks are not as important.

Answer (score 1):

With simulated data similar to yours with peak heights of 100 - 150 unit, the following works perfectly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

x = np.array(1400 - 0.002 * np.linspace(0,700_000,700_000))
# add peaks 100 - 150 units high
for i in range(70_000,630_000,70_000):
    x[i] += np.random.rand()*50+100

peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, threshold=100)
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```

[image]

In this simulated case, the default settings (i.e. `find_peaks(x)`) yield the same result.

The [`threshold`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) parameter specifies the minimum elevation (or min and max elevation if two values are given) of the peak over the curve.

You may also want to eliminate any possible `nan`s first:

> Warning
> This function may return unexpected results for data containing NaNs.
> To avoid this, NaNs should either be removed or replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing around with the `prominence` value, I have tried doing this and by tweaking the prominence value, i get different results.I suppose that your range is too great and hence setting a `prominence` value of 1 will get you bad results.

> The prominence of a peak measures how much a peak stands out from the surrounding baseline of the signal and is defined as the vertical distance between the peak and its lowest contour line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import numpy as np
x = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(1000,100))
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, prominence=1)
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")

plt.show()
```

`prominence` value of 1
[image: prominence value of 1]

`prominence` value of 10
[image]

`prominence` value of 100
[image]

**OR**

You can simply pass in the distance parameter of the `x-axis` which can be achieved by `peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, distance=50000)`